# How to specify method parameters while overriding without casting?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

i have a question regarding method-overriding which probably is influenced by some other aspects so i hope the question is sufficiently specific. 
Context: i try to construct a simple calculator for prices of certain objects BUT the "kind of price" shall be decoupled from the rest of the logic so that the client only needs to know the following interface.

I think it is best explained with the basic code where my problem starts.

```
public interface InterfacePrice {
    public InterfacePrice addPrices(InterfacePrice price1, InterfacePrice price2);
    public InterfacePrice subtractPrices(InterfacePrice price1, InterfacePrice price2);
    public String priceToString();
}
```

So this is what i should be able to do with two prices.
Now i tried to specify this some more:

```
public class BnSPrice implements InterfacePrice {
    int gold = 0;
    int silver = 0;
    int copper = 0;
    //the following will obviously not compile but i hope it helps explain
    @Override
    public InterfacePrice addPrices(BnSPrice price1, BnSPrice price2) {
    return null;
    [...more code here...]
}
```

So what i would like to do is write a simple add-method based on the fact 100 copper are one silver and so on. Now my problem:
the compiler won't allow me to change the parameters to type BnSPrice which i understand, i just want to illustrate the problem. It doesn't make sense to try adding some golds and silvers of two concrete prices if i don't know they have the right type so the first thing that comes to my mind to get the correct behaviour is overriding the method with the normal InterfacePrice parameters and making a typecheck at the begin of the method and casting to the propper type but that seems not very efficient or beautiful.

Question: how can i change the design to get the flexibility to add other price models later while my client-code only needs to know the interface?
(I am just learning java so plese forgive me if the question has some obvious answer i don't see.) Can it be solved by using generics? (I don't know much about those...i'm struggeling to get the usage of generics into my mind.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So is your question how can you only allow addPrice to be called with compatible price objects (e.g. gold and silver), but not with incompatible types? Or just how can you add two different objects that both use that same interface?

Comment: First, davidxxx's answer is a clear hit to the problem i had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to apply in derived classes, some constraints on the parameters of parent methods, Generics could help you.

With Generics, you can also choose to return in the method the parameterized type or `InterfacePrice`.

As in your concrete class example, you write :

```
@Override
public InterfacePrice addPrices(BnSPrice price1, BnSPrice price2) {
```

I will give an example that follows this way for the addPrices() method and for the subtractPrices() method, I will use the way where we want to return the specific type .

You could create a Generic interface:

```
public interface InterfacePrice<T extends InterfacePrice<T>> {
    public InterfacePrice<T> addPrices(T price1, T price2);
    public T subtractPrices(T price1, T price2);
    public String priceToString();
}
```

And here is a implementation of it :

```
public class BnSPrice implements InterfacePrice<BnSPrice> {
    int gold = 0;
    int silver = 0;
    int copper = 0;

    @Override
    public InterfacePrice<?> addPrices(BnSPrice price1, BnSPrice price2) {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public BnSPrice subtractPrices(BnSPrice price1, BnSPrice price2) {
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public String priceToString() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense! Thanks for your nice and concise answer; that really helped me! Now i have a small follow up question: is the structure of the problem i described the main point what generics are made for?

Comment: You are welcome :) Clearly, if you program by interface and manipulate interfaces in processing code you don't need to perform instanceof and cast in your actual code. This use of Generics allows in a some way to fill the lack of method overriding/implementing in Java where the parameter types of the overloaded/implemented methods has to be the same as those defined in the original definition. In some cases it is desirable because you deem that applying this constraint on the param type is important . In other cases, it is an overhead and it violates the liskov principle for no good reason.

Comment: Hm, ok..i googled for liskov principle. Your solution to my problem doesn't violate this or am i wrong?

Comment: Hmm. You are may be right for Liskov. In fact what I wanted to say is you cannot program by interface any longer. This code doesn't compile : `InterfacePrice<? extends InterfacePrice<?>> price = new BnSPrice();
  price.addPrices(new BnSPrice(), new BnSPrice());` while without generics usage this code compiles : `InterfacePrice price = new BnSPrice();
  price.addPrices(new BnSPrice(), new BnSPrice());`

Comment: Sorry i'm late with my answer; i don't really understand some things about yours.IntelliJ shows me a "cannot resolve symbol: addPrice"-error/warning, so it won't compile like you said (i was trying to test your first example with slight difference, addPrices->addPrice, only one parameter).But why is that the case when the addPrice method is available to every InterfacePrice there is. 

With your last comment, which i probably don't understand correctly, i am uncertain what we won with using generics if i loose the ability to program to an interface rather than to a specific implementation.